# REACT NATIVE: Scroll View keep bouncing back up to the top doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get my ScrollView to scroll down so I can see all my views but it keeps bouncing back up to the top.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCIim.jpg)

The White panels below Physiological Classification are in the ScrollView and are supposed to scroll but it just bounces back to the top.

Here is where my ScrollView is

```
_renderContent = (section) => {
    section.arrow = !(section.arrow);
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <QuestionPanels
          Questions={section.Questions}
          pickerDefaultValues={section.pickerDefaultValues}
          pickerItemNames={section.pickerItemNames}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };
```

Question Panels is just a component that generates Views based on a json file. If relevant here is the code for that as well.

```
import React, { Component, useState, setState} from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import styles from '../../Styles/GeneralStyles';
import Picker from '../Picker/Picker'
import appData from '../../DataSheet/appData.json';


const Panel = (props) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.dropDownCardPanel}>
      <View style={styles.QuestionPanel}>
        <Text style={styles.QuestionText}>{props.Question}</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.AnswerPanel}>
        <Picker
          defaultVal= {props.pickerDefaultValues}
          showButton={false}
          pickerItemNames={props.pickerItemNames}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default class QuestionairePanels extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }
  render() {

    var panelList = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < this.props.Questions.length; i++){
      panelList.push(
        <Panel
               key={i}
               Question={this.props.Questions[i]}
               pickerDefaultValues ={this.props.pickerDefaultValues[i]}
               pickerItemNames = {this.props.pickerItemNames[i]}
        />
      );
    }

    return(
      <View>
        {panelList}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are the styles that matter for this

```
dropDownCardPanel: {
    height: 200,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: '#faf2f2',
    paddingTop: 5,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
  },
  dropDownCardPanelText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    color: "black",
    marginLeft: 10
  },
  icon: {
    left: 20,
  },
  QuestionPanel: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "60%",
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    left: 3,
    marginRight: 5,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
  QuestionText: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  AnswerPanel: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "40%",
    right: 3
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why I was not able to scroll was that the  tag needs a specific height for it to render for a scroll. So to fix this I had to put a view around the  and set it to a specific height.

Corrected Code

```
section.arrow = !(section.arrow);
    var scrollHeight = (section.Questions.length > 2) ? 600 : 400;
    var headerDisplay = (section.name.match("Physiologic")) ? section.name + " Variables" : "Select Dominant Final Diagnosis";
    return (
      <View style={{height: scrollHeight}}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.dropDownCardPanelHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.dropDownCardPanelHeaderText}>
              {headerDisplay}
            </Text>
          </View>
          <QuestionPanels
            Questions={section.Questions}
            pickerItemNames={section.pickerItemNames}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Later I will try to use Flex to set the height so the react native project can scale to all screens but so far it works for iOS